# when reading docker events, how to quit docker events instead of entire program?

Tags: bash, docker, break

The requirement is inside a big while loop, given a specific docker container ID, I need to monitor the docker stop event using docker event command. When I found the event, I need to quit the docker event read.

The simplified bash script I wrote is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

while true
do 
    ## other logics
    docker events --filter='container=...'  --filter='event=stop' | while read event
        do 
              echo $event
              break
        done      
     echo "got here"
     ## other logics
done
```

So in one bash session, I would run this script, in another bash session, I would type the following command:
docker container stop cassandra-1

The problem is when I execute this bash program, I can capture the stop event, and print the event, but this command will read event repeated. How to quit the docker events and print "got here" ?

I've spent lots of time searching solution online, but can't find any good approach. I once considered using break, but it doesn't work, and I also considered kill -9 $$, but I will quit the entire script program. But I only need to quit the docker event instead of big while loop.

any good advice? Thanks so much!

Comment: Replace `break` with `break 2`?

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. Replace break with break 2 cannot work. I found the solution. Key point is to know how docker event command actually work. Based on my research, docker event will generate a process and stuck in the foreground process. You should CTRL+C to quit (refer to: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/). So you can not use break to get out of it. The approach is to execute docker event command in the background job and kill it when I found the event.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Key point is to know how docker event command actually work. Based on my research, docker event will generate a process and stuck in the foreground process. You should CTRL+C to quit (refer to: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events). So you can not use break to get out of it. The approach is to execute docker event command in the background job and kill it when I found the event.

the code is as follows:

```
  (docker events --filter 'container='"$container_id"'' --filter 'event=stop' &) | while read event
   do 
     # kill this backgroud process 
     pkill -f "docker event.*stop"
   done
```

Comment: Be aware that there could be "collateral damage" with a pkill - you could kill other monitors - so this is not a scaleable solution.

Comment: Argh silly comments edit rule :)

So using break is the better way with the docker events process backgrounded... Have to say it is weird. Anyway this works fine:

 (docker events --filter 'event=stop' &) | while read event;    do       echo it stopped; break;    done

Comment: Instead of using `pkill -f "docker event.*stop"`, you could run `kill $!` - this command kills the most recently backgrounded job (with in a given shell). So it shouldn't pose any risk of potentially killing other monitors (the problem that @PaulHedderly mentioned)